# How to change the default username and password for Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I am running Memgraph using docker with the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 7687:7687 memgraph/memgraph --memory-limit=50 --log-level=TRACE
```

I have been looking at the available memgraph [configuration settings](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/configuration) but I can't seem to find a setting like `--username=memgraph` or `--password=test`.

How do I change the default username and password?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation for user management at https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/users.

Did you try to run the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 -e MGCONSOLE="--username <username> --password <password>" memgraph/memgraph-platform
```

Or in your case I guess it would be something like:

```
docker run -it -p 7687:7687 memgraph/memgraph --memory-limit=50 --log-level=TRACE MGCONSOLE="--username <username> --password <password>"
```